# How to remove duplicate line items from a file?

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate line items from my file, need to check duplicate based of few fields.

myfile.txt

```
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/11/2017
productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc2,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/12/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/11/2017
productItem2 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice991,ProductModelHP123,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
```

As per above example, I want to eliminate duplicate records - in this case productItem1 has duplicate. I want to remove duplicated based on these field (ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,10/06/206 which is index 0, index 1 and index 3).

I would like to keep the record which is having recent date. In this example 01/12/2017 is greater date for productItem1 .

I've scenario where key can have same value for example: productItem2 but the field which I've mentioned index 0, index 1 and index 3 are different so it should not consider as duplicate.

How can we eliminate in Python

Output should be: newFile.txt

```
productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc2,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/12/2017
productItem2 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice991,ProductModelHP123,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
```

What's the elegant way of eliminating duplicate record? I tried in shell script but that's not giving me the expected output.

It would be really appreciated if someone can help us to solve in pythonic way

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? You could for example put the items in a dictionary, using the desired columns as key.

Answer (score 2):

First, what actually *did* happen with your attempt to do it from the shell?  UNIX (and Linux) has the [uniq](https://shapeshed.com/unix-uniq/) command that does just this.

In Python the solution depends on your needs.  Do you have to retain the original order of the records?  If not, then you can simply add each line, as a string, to a set.  When you hit end of file, just write the set to your destination file.

If you need to retain the order, then maintain a set with seen items.  For each line, if the item is not in the set, then write it to the destination file and add it to the set.  If it's been seen before, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also fairly new to python, but I can try to give you some advice on where to go, honestly not 100% sure I can help, but I will try.

You could maybe use a for loop for comparing each item from the list against the other items in each list, and if it finds it, use the replace() function and that should get rid of it. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import re
data = [re.split('[,\s]', i) for i in open('filename.txt').read().split("\n")][1:-1]
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
   d[i[0]].append(i[1:])

new_data = {a:[(c, list(d)) for c, d in itertools.groupby(sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])] for a, b in d.items()}
new_final_data = {a:min(b, key=lambda x:len(x[-1])) if len(b) > 1 else b[-1] for a, b in new_data.items()}
final_list = []
for a, b in new_final_data.items():
     temp1_data = [' '.join(',' if not c else c for c in d) for d in b[-1]]
     for c in temp1_data:
         final_list.append(a+" "+c)

print('\n'.join(final_list))
```

Output:

```
productItem1 ProductName11 ProdutctPrice27 ProductModelHP11 10/06/2016 ProductDescription-abc1 , , , , , 01/12/2017
productItem2 ProductName12 ProdutctPrice99 ProductModelHP12 10/06/2016 ProductDescription-abc2 , , , , , 09/02/2017
productItem2 ProductName13 ProdutctPrice991 ProductModelHP123 10/06/2016 ProductDescription-abc3 , , , , , 09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13 ProdutctPrice87 ProductModelHP13 10/06/2016 ProductDescription-abc3 , , , , , 09/02/2017
```

Comment: Thanks Ajax1234 - but its not printing the right output. productItem2 has two records - keys are same but the field which we are seeing to identify the duplicate records that are different? How will handle that scenario?

Comment: @learnjquery please see my recent edit.